# Значение Select в обработчике php

Tags: php, html, select

В зависимости от того, какой пункт выбран, после нажатия кнопки должен выполняться свой SQL запрос. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как связать значение селекта с php обработкой. Такой же вопрос и к чекбоксу. Код:

```
if(isset($_POST['show-select']))
{
    $strSQL="SELECT * FROM worktime WHERE year(date)= year(now()) AND week(date, 1) = week(now(), 1) AND pcid='".$_SESSION['currpcid']."' AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY date DESC"; //Выбор записей за неделю
}
<form action="" method="post" name="dropdownlist" id="select-interval">
    <select class="select rounded shadow" id="workname" size="1">
        <option disabled selected>Выберите интервал</option>
        <option value="week">Неделя</option>
        <option value="month">Месяц</option>
        <option value="month3">Квартал</option>
        <option data-type="range">Выберите даты...</option>
    </select>
<input class="submit color_button rounded" type="submit" value="Выбрать" name="show-select" id="submit" /><Br>
<input type="checkbox" name="otchet" value="a1">Создать отчет
</form>
```

Comment: Кажется, Вы забыли присвоить name этому select

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь вам надо поставить атрибут `name` к данному `select`

```
if(isset($_POST['show-select']))
{

echo $_POST['interval']; // здесь ваше значение от select
echo $_POST['otchet']; // здесь ваше значение от checkbox (или a1 или пустота)


    $strSQL="SELECT * FROM worktime WHERE year(date)= year(now()) AND week(date, 1) = week(now(), 1) AND pcid='".$_SESSION['currpcid']."' AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY date DESC"; //Выбор записей за неделю
}


    <form action="" method="post" name="dropdownlist" id="select-interval">
    <select name="interval" class="select rounded shadow" id="workname" size="1">
            <option disabled selected>Выберите интервал</option>
            <option value="week">Неделя</option>
            <option value="month">Месяц</option>
            <option value="month3">Квартал</option>
            <option data-type="range">Выберите даты...</option>
        </select>
    <input class="submit color_button rounded" type="submit" value="Выбрать" name="show-select" id="submit" /><Br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otchet" value="a1">Создать отчет
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

У `select` должно быть имя:

```
<select name='show-select' ...>
```

У чекбокса

```
<input type="checkbox" name="otchet" value="a1">
```

Если он будет нажат, то `$_POST['otchet']` будет равен `a1`,

 если не будет нажат, то  `$_POST['otchet']` будет пуст